# Why is that type double instead of float?

Tags: c++, floating-point, language-lawyer, implicit-conversion

**Problem:** In a homework problem (it is to be done on paper with a pen so no coding) I must determine the type and value of an addition performed in C++.

```
1 + 0.5
```

**What I've answered is:**

- Type float (because I thought that `integer + float = float`)
- Value 1.5 (As far as I know when two different datatypes are added, 
  the result of the addition is going to be converted to the datatype that does not loose any information.)

**Solution says:**

- Type: double
- Value: 1.5

**My Question:** Why is 0.5 a double and not a float? How can I distingish between a float and a double? I mean, 0.5 looks to me like a float and a double.

Comment: `0.5f` is a float literal.  `0.5` is a double literal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, yes. `integer` + `float` = `float`. You are correct about that part.

The issue is not with that, but rather your assumption that `0.5` is a `float`. It is not. In C++, [float literals are followed by an f](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal) meaning that `0.5f` is a float. However, `0.5` is actually a `double`. That means that your equation is now:

```
integer + double = double
```

As you can see, this result is a double. That is why the correct answer to your question is that the resulting type is a double.

---

By the way, to clear the record, technically what's going on here isn't `integer + double = double`. What is happening is that the `1` is falling subject to [implicit conversion](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/type-conversion-in-c/). Essentially, the `1` is converted to a `double`, since the other side of the operation is a `double` as well. This way, the computer is adding the same types and not different ones. That means that the actual addition taking place here is more like:

```
double + double = double
```

Comment: Omg, thank you for that awesome explaination ! So when a number X.X is followed by an f: X.Xf then and only then that Number is a float, if a number is not followed by an f, then it’s double, right?

Comment: You're welcome. If you'd like to show your appreciation, you can upvote my answer, or accept it if you think it's better than the other answer (which I'll admit is also a good one too).

Comment: Also, yes. You are correct. If it's not followed by anything (it can actually be followed by an `L`, too, I think, for long doubles), then it is a double by default.

Comment: That was an accept, but that's fine. I'll take it for now. Don't be afraid to change the accepted answer later if you need to.

Answer (score 7):

In C++, floating point literals without a type suffix are `double` by default. If you want it to be `float`, you need to specify the `f` suffix, like `0.5f`.

Comment: Thank you for that great explaination too, if there is a number without a point, let‘s say 7, but it is followed by an f: 7f then 7f is float too, right ? :-)

Comment: No, you have to a have a dot before the f, so `7.f` is correct.